# Concatenate two columns containing lists python

Tags: python, pandas

How do I concatenate two columns having lists such that there are no duplicates in the resultant list.

```
df:

A         B  

[a,b]   [c,d,a,b]
[s,d]   [d,f]
```

Expected Result in new column:

```
A_B
[a,b,c,d]
[s,d,f]
```

Comment: Whenever you say something like "no duplicates in list" what you actually mean is that you want a set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Crude but succint

```
df.sum(1).map(set).map(list).to_frame('_'.join(df))

            A_B
0  [a, d, b, c]
1     [s, d, f]
```

---

#### Less crude and less succint

But probably better

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'_'.join(df): [[*set().union(*t)] for t in zip(*map(df.get, df))]},
    df.index,
)

            A_B
0  [a, d, b, c]
1     [s, d, f]
```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[[*'ab'], [*'sd']], B=[[*'cdab'], [*'df']]))
```

Comment: The resultant column should not have duplicates.

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks.  Will correct.

Comment: Oh.. that -1 wasn't me. :)

Comment: Oh I figured it wasn't (-:  No worries.